# asynchronous xhr request within setInterval not working | Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, setinterval

I'm building a tracking library to send events to the backend. An event should be created every 5 seconds (configurable) and sent into the tracking queue, and the tracking queue should be sent to the backend and emptied every 5 seconds (also configurable). The expected behaviour is that an event should be sent to the backend every 5 seconds.

When I was just console.logging the events, everything was working as expected, but when I implemented the xhr request, the interval events were only created every 9 seconds or so. So an event would be sent to the backend, only once every two times the 'post' function fired.

```
sendData: function(){
    var toSend = [].concat(Tracking.__tracking_queue);
    if(toSend.length !== 0){
        var sendData = this.__stringifyAndSetHeaders(toSend);
        Tracking.postData(sendData);
    }
},

postData: function(sendData){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        Tracking.__tracking_queue = [];
    };
    xhr.open("POST", sendData.url, true);
    Object.keys(sendData.headers).forEach(function(key){
        xhr.setRequestHeader([key], sendData.headers[key]);
    });
    xhr.send(sendData.body);
}
```

The backend is receiving the data, but not at the correct times. sendData is being called from within a setInterval loop.

```
    setInterval(function(){
        self.sendData()
    }, 5000);
```

I had the same setup working perfectly before, in another file using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), but I cannot use axios in this use-case.

Comment: did you tried by only calling `sendData()` instead of `self.sendData()`?

Comment: `Tracking.__tracking_queue = [];` appears to be called in the wrong location. If something was added to the queue between the time you build the data and the Ajax call is returned, you will loose the data.

Comment: create a demo that reproduces problem. Should also add some error handling

Comment: @brk, these functions are within an object variable. I need to set 'self' for it to work. The function is being called.

Comment: @epascarello, good catch, you genius, that's exactly what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the tracking data at the wrong location. You read the data, than make a request, after the request is done, you delete the data. There is a period of time where data can come into the queue between the request and when it finishes.

```
sendData: function(){
    var toSend = [].concat(Tracking.__tracking_queue);
    if(toSend.length !== 0){
        var sendData = this.__stringifyAndSetHeaders(toSend);
        Tracking.__tracking_queue = [];  //clear it here
        Tracking.postData(sendData);
    }
},

postData: function(sendData){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        //Tracking.__tracking_queue = [];  //don't clear it here
    };
    xhr.open("POST", sendData.url, true);
    Object.keys(sendData.headers).forEach(function(key){
        xhr.setRequestHeader([key], sendData.headers[key]);
    });
    xhr.send(sendData.body);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the issue.